# Adding Text Overlay to a set of images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, overlay

I am in the process of creating a website for my sister! (solely for practice purposes). I cannot get the desired effect! I want the text overlay, so when I hover over the image, the image turns opaque and text appears. I have been trying nearly all day, and I cannot get it. I also tried putting each image in a separate div and container, yet they are stacked on top of each other and still I cannot get the desired effect.

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Emma Allerd Website</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CDN  -->

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome CDN  -->

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/661ef34abd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Google Fonts  -->

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cedarville+Cursive&family=Cutive+Mono&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <!-- Nav Bar -->

    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light p-4">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <h1 class="logo-margin logo-text">Emma Allard</h1>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto navbar-margin navbar-text">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link link-text" href="#about-address">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Projects
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#championnet">Championnet</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#project2">Project Name 2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#project3">Project Name 3</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link link-text" href="https://www.instagram.com/atelier.m_co" target="_blank">Instagram</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link link-text" href="#contact-address">Contact</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <!-- Portfolio Pictures  -->

    <hr id="championnet">

    <section>
        <div class="container port-pictures">
            <div class="row row-padding">
                <div class="col-lg">
                    <img class="empic-tall1" src="Emma_Allerd_Images/empic7.jpg" alt="tc-logo">
                    <img class="empic-short1" src="Emma_Allerd_Images/emmapic2.jpg" alt="tc-logo">
                    <img class="empic-tall1" src="Emma_Allerd_Images/emmapic3.jpg" alt="tc-logo">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-padding">
                <div class="col-lg">
                    <img class="empic-short2" src="Emma_Allerd_Images/emmapic4.jpg" alt="tc-logo">
                    <img class="empic-tall2" src="Emma_Allerd_Images/emmapic5.jpg" alt="tc-logo">
                    <img class="empic-short2" src="Emma_Allerd_Images/emmapic6.jpg" alt="tc-logo">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-padding">
                <div class="col-lg">
                    <img class="empic-tall1" src="Emma_Allerd_Images/emmapic1.jpg" alt="tc-logo">
                    <img class="empic-short1" src="Emma_Allerd_Images/emmapic2.jpg" alt="tc-logo">
                    <img class="empic-tall1" src="Emma_Allerd_Images/emmapic3.jpg" alt="tc-logo">
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
.port-pictures{
    margin-top: 10rem;
    text-align: center ;
}

.navbar-margin{
    margin-right: 12rem;
}

.logo-margin{
    margin-left: 12.5rem;
}

.empic-tall1{
    height: 375px;
    width: 321px;
}
.empic-tall1a{
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
}

.empic-short1{
    height: 375px;
    width: 446px;
}
.empic-tall2{
    height: 332px;
    width: 279px;

}
.empic-short2{
    height: 332px;
    width: 403px;
}

.row-padding{
    padding-bottom: .3rem;
}

.navbar-text{
    font-family: 'Cutive Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    
}
.logo-text{
    color: #000281;
    font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive', cursive;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

hr{
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?  JavaScript is an entirely different language.  ‘Java’ and ‘JavaScript’ are as similar as ’car’ and ‘cartoon’.

Comment: Could you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and show a small example of the problem. Also please explain what you mean by 'image turns opaque' - is it the opposite, that it turns a bit transparent?

Comment: Also no use of `:hover` anywhere in the CSS code, so I'm not sure how you expect to get a hover effect without using `:hover`. Unless the Bootstrap classes handle that for you, then disregard. You also probably shouldn't put your sister's real name in the code, at least when posting here.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).